# Custom Image Cropper in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I'm trying to make a custom image splitter/cropper. I have searched for packages, but none of them really suit my needs.

What I need is the following:

- A way to crop the image like in Snapseed or Google Photos
- Show a custom grid over the image.

Something similar to what is shown below:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUnRx.jpg)

How would I do this in flutter?